# Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' grails

Tags: grails, jakarta-mail

grails cannot create bean.

this is my config.groovy for mail.

```
grails {
    mail {
        grails.mail.jndiName = "java:comp/env/mail/mailSession"
    }
}
```

and this is for mail/mailSession jndi at context.xml

```
<Resource name="mail/mailSession"
                  auth="Container"
                type="javax.mail.Session"
                mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
                mail.smtp.port="465"
                mail.smtp.auth="true"
                mail.smtp.user="abc_yes@gmail.com"
                password="abc123"
                mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
                mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
    />
```

iam using tomcat 7 and i put war file to websapp/ROOT.war

and this is an error what i get when i try to run it.

```
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mailSession' while setting bean property 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSession': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSession': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
        at org.apache.naming.factory.MailSessionFactory.getObjectInstance(MailSessionFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 63 more

Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: Start: Loading persisted sessions
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: Loading persisted sessions from SESSIONS.ser
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: No persisted data file found
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE: Stopping filters
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stopInternal
FINE: Stopping
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
FINE: Unloading persisted sessions
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:13 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
FINE: No persisted sessions to unload
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /root/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 59,132 ms
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 20, 2015 1:40:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 59307 ms
```

how can i resolved this?

i already move mail.jar, mysq connector and activation.jar to lib..like this

[image]

this is new error..

```
Configuring event listener class 'org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@50faece'
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE: Sending application start events
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2015-10-20 16:47:49,595 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'int'
        at CorporateUserService.<clinit>(CorporateUserService.groovy:31)
        ... 6 more
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'int'
        at CorporateUserService.<clinit>(CorporateUserService.groovy:31)
        ... 6 more

Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: Start: Loading persisted sessions
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: Loading persisted sessions from SESSIONS.ser
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
FINE: No persisted data file found
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE: Stopping filters
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stopInternal
FINE: Stopping
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
FINE: Unloading persisted sessions
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
FINE: No persisted sessions to unload
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /root/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 29,869 ms
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 20, 2015 4:47:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 30090 ms
```

Comment: Have you added Java mail to the classpath? The exception says no

Comment: no...did you  mean setenv.sh ? how?

Comment: @tim_yates but i see mai.jar in WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator`. Since `javax.mail.Authenticator` is missing you must add `activation.jar` which is the library who contains this class, you can download it from [here](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar) and add to your `WEB-INF/lib`.

If you use gradle to build your project it will resolve this dependencies for you simply adding `javax.mail` since `activation` is a dependency of it. In gradle simple using this solves the required dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.1'
}
```

Additionally seems that newer versions of `1.4.1` for `javax.mail` doesn't have this dependency, so instead of use `javax.mail 1.4.1` and `javax.activation 1.1` you can simply use a newer `javax.mail` like 1.5.4 which seems the last stable version, you can download from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/javax.mail-api/1.5.4/javax.mail-api-1.5.4.jar)

Hope it helps,

Comment: see my edit post, i tried to copy mail.jar anda activation.jar to tomcat/websapp/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: but there's have activation-1.1.jar , mail-1.4.1.jar and mail-1.4.3.jar..why theres 2 kind mail.jar?

Comment: You only need one of each...  Throwing jars in the same folder may be the cause of your problem

Comment: but i dont know why theres have two kind mail.jar..at my project ..i just import mail-1.4.1.jar to lib

Comment: @akiong simply copy mail-1.4.1 and activation-1.1 to your `WEB-INF/lib`, avoid to use two different versions of the same library. Also why you copy this libs to `ROOT` webapp (`tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`)? keep the jars in your app and simply deploy it in your tomcat.

Comment: @albciff  `WEB-INF/lib` isnot same with `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: @akiong no is not, `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` is the ROOT application which comes with tomcats to show tomcat manager an so on (depends on your installation, config, etc). Your webapp could normally deployed in `tomcat/webapps/yourAppName`, so your `WEB-INF/lib` is the one located in this directory, however it's not necessary that you copy your libs manually to this folder, since if your app is correctly packaged in for example a `war` and this libs are in your project tomcats will deploy correctly this files, anyway to make sure you can check it `tomcat/webapps/yourAppName/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: but `tomcat/webapps/AppName/WEB-INF/lib` already have `activation-1.1.jar` and `mail-1.4.1.jar` .. and i still get this error  `Error creating bean with name 'mailSender': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mailSession' while setting bean property 'session';`

Comment: @akiong... it's strange, then I'll recommend you that try to remove both : activation and mail-1.4.1 and use directly `mail-1.5.4` which doesn't have the dependency http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/javax.mail-api/1.5.4/javax.mail-api-1.5.4.jar

Comment: actually, its very confuse...my project run without any error in localhost with grails run-app..but when i create it to war file and deploy it to server...then that error appear ..

Comment: @akiong then probably your application is ok and the problem comes from the container, check that in tomcat common libs `tomcat\common` or in `tomcat\lib` there are also a `mail.jar` which is probably provoking the problem.

Comment: oh? then must i put `mysql-connector.jar` and `mail.jar` to `tomcat\lib` ? before i put `mysql-connector.jar` and `mail.jar` to `tomcat\lib`...i got defferent error..see my post

Comment: @akiong seems that now it's loading correctly the jars and now your problem comes from your bussiness logic... and it's a different problem so I think you must create a new question if you need help on it.

Comment: BTW, you can [get rid of the socket factory setting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: @BillShannon good point `:)`, the OP must review his configuration and the use of `mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"`.